# Embedded Chocolatey Installer Failing

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-prompt, chocolatey

I keep getting the same error with my chocolatey package: `Exit code was '-1'`. I am not sure if it is something wrong with my `chocolateyinstall.ps1` or the `setup.exe` I am using to make this embedded installer. The image below shows both the `chocolateyinstall.ps1` and the cmd when trying to run `choco install (packagename)`. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
$packageArgs = @{
packageName = 'armrvds'
fileType = 'exe'
file = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.Mycommand.Definition)\setup.exe"
validExitCodes = @(0)
softwareName = 'ARM RVDS 4.1*'

Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage @packageArgs
```

https://ibb.co/Mpnh0mq

Comment: Please add your code inline instead of linking to an image of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exit code was '-1'` means that the exit code of the installer was `-1`, and not `0` or another acceptable exit code to be treated as successful. You will need to figure out why your `setup.exe` is failing. You may be able to find more information about why the installer failed if you look at `C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log` as the error indicates.

---

One thing I notice is you are not setting the silent installation arguments as part of your arguments to `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage`, which at a minimum may cause your package to require interactivity (you don't want this). You should find out what the silent installation arguments are to `setup.exe`.

In your case, it looks like RVDS uses a [different program](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dsi0033g/DSI0033G_rvds_install_guide.pdf) to install silently (page 7). Note that this is for 3.1, not 4.1, so you should either try to find up to date documentation, or see if `setupcli` still exists in 4.1 and start looking at the parameters it supports.